# Display active link en responsive menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, label, responsive

I'm having trouble  displaying the active link at the top of my responsive menu, I want it to appear on the top when selected, it already applies the active css style when selected but it doesn't shows it at the top, I'm not sure how to make it work out maybe a label?
Here's my code
CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        height: auto;
        }   
    ul.topnav .active {
        color: #ee1921;
        border-bottom: none!important;
        font-size: 20px;
        }
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
        }
    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        }
    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 20px 20px 15px 20px;
        }
ul.topnav.responsive .active {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        }
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="navItem" href="FAQ-sports.html">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="FAQ-casino.html"  class="navItem">Casino</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Slots"  class="navItem">Slots</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Vegas"  class="navItem">Vegas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Bingo"  class="active">Bingo</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
```

And the jquery script is:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the parent, change the `.active` class to be on the `li` instead (so that it's a flex-child of the flex-parent), then `.active { order: -1; }` to put that `li` at the beginning of the list.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    height: auto;
  }
  ul.topnav .active a {
    color: #ee1921;
    border-bottom: none!important;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 20px 15px 20px;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive .active a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  .topnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .active {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="navItem" href="FAQ-sports.html">Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href="FAQ-casino.html" class="navItem">Casino</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Slots" class="navItem">Slots</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Vegas" class="navItem">Vegas</a></li class="active">
  <li class="active"><a href="#Bingo" class="">Bingo</a></li>
  <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
```